# Неоднозначность вызова Aggregate

Tags: pascal, linq, pascalabc.net

Задача: Даны целые числа A и B (A < B). Используя методы Range и Average, найти среднее арифметическое квадратов всех целых чисел от A до B включительно: (A2 + (A+1)2 + … + B2)/(B − A + 1) (как вещественное число).
Есть код, который компилируется нормально:

```
begin
  Range(ReadlnInteger('A:'), ReadlnInteger('B:')).Select(x -> Sqr(x)).Average();
end.
```

Однако, следующий код не работает:

```
begin
  Range(ReadlnInteger('A:'), ReadlnInteger('B:')).Average(x -> Sqr(x));
end.
```

Как исправить второй код?

Answer (score -1):

Это плохой автовывод типов в PascalABC.NET. Используйте первый код с Average без параметров

Comment: Хорошо, я Вас понял.

Comment: Но ведь типы можно подсказать?